# SpaCy Rule Based Phrase Matching for Hello World

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am doing ruled based phrase matching in Spacy. I am trying the following example but it is not working.

**Example**

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp('Hello world!')

pattern = [{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"IS_PUNCT": True}, {"LOWER": "world"}]

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('HelloWorld', None, pattern)

matches = matcher(doc)
print(matches)
```

then final `matches` is giving empty string. Would you please correct me?

Comment: Your current code also returns `[]`. `pattern = [{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"LOWER": "world"}]` will match.

Comment: I want 'IS_PUNCT' as well.

Comment: Great. it is working. Please explain why this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match either `hello world` and also `hello, world`, you may use

```
pattern = [{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"IS_PUNCT": True, "OP" : "?"}, {"LOWER": "world"}]
```

The `{"IS_PUNCT": True, "OP" : "?"}` means that the token of type *punctuation* can exist 1 or 0 times (due to `"OP" : "?"`) between `hello` and `world`.

See more about [Operators and quantifiers](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#quantifiers) in Spacy documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern matches `Hello, world` with a punctuation token in the middle, not `Hello world`

Comment: It should match a combination of any of these three. like 'Hello, world!' should give `Hello, world` and `Hello world!` should just give `Hello world`

Comment: Then you'll need to edit the pattern! The docs are here: https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#matcher, more specifically: https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#quantifiers